# Firefox is not working with maven

Tags: firefox, maven-2, selenium-rc

[image: Stuck at launch]
I have two program with and without maven. Without maven code is able to launch firefox. But with maven is not able to launch firefox. I have set environment variables. I am using eclipse IDE, when i try to run as JUnit test, firefox doesn't launch. Firefox version 11.0. I am using selenium RC.
Including Logs:

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpServer.java:893) - Contexts at /selenium-server/driver/:    [/selenium-server/driver/*=[HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server    /driver]], /selenium-server/*=[HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]], /=[HttpContext[/,/]]]`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpServer.java:907) - Try HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver],0`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpServer.java:907) - Try HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server],0`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpContext.java:1529) - Handler org.openqa.jetty.http.handler.SecurityHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpContext.java:1529) - Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.StaticContentHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (ResourceHandler.java:239) - PATH=/driver/ RESOURCE=file:/E:/Automation/Selenium/Eclipse_Workspace/AutomationBuildTest9WithMaven/MISSING%20RESOURCE`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (ResourceHandler.java:287) - Looking for file:/E:/Automation/Selenium/Eclipse_Workspace/AutomationBuildTest9WithMaven/MISSING%20RESOURCE`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpContext.java:1529) - Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.SessionExtensionJsHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpContext.java:1529) - Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SingleTestSuiteResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpContext.java:1529) - Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SeleniumHTMLRunnerResultsHandler@19efb05`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpContext.java:1529) - Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.CachedContentTestHandler@22c95b`

`[Apr 03 12:48:45] DEBUG (HttpContext.java:1529) - Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]`

`[Apr 03 12:49:45] DEBUG (LogSupport.java:36) - IGNORED`

`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:450)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.acceptSocket(ThreadedServer.java:432)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer$Acceptor.run(ThreadedServer.java:634)`

It gets stuck at..
Launching Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not yet support Firefox 11.  The 2.21 release should, but it isn't (quite) ready yet.  Back off to Firefox 10 if you need it now.

Comment: It is supporting firefox without maven. Everything is working fine without maven but with maven it launches firefox but URL does not get populated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated selenium version inside pom.xml. if not updated please update to selnium server version 2.21 and try